# How close toolbar Espresso

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have layout with coordinatlayout, AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout. I want to write a test that clicks on the last item in the list. I scroll through the list until the end, however, the desired item is hidden from the espresso.To scroll through the list, I use:
`onView(withId(R.id.widget_recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(3));`
To hide, scroll through the toolbar, I tried the following code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.coordinator_layout)).perform(swipeUp());
onView(withId(R.id.toolbar)).perform(swipeUp());
```

But this code hides the toolbar only half, but it's not enough. Here is the code of the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    >
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.makeramen.RoundedImageView
                            style="@style/AvatarImage.MainActivity"
                            android:id="@+id/iv_avatar"
                            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"/>

                        <com.akbars.bankok.views.custom.TextViewFonted
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_avatar"
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            app:customFont="Roboto-Medium.ttf"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

                        <com.akbars.bankok.views.custom.TextViewFonted
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textSize="16sp"
                            app:customFont="Roboto-Light.ttf"
                            android:id="@+id/tv_balance"
                            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_avatar"
                            android:layout_below="@id/name"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>
                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <com.akbars.bankok.views.custom.SwipeEnableViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/main_view_pager"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/tab_bar_layout_height"/>

        <com.akbars.bankok.views.custom.CustomTabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_tab"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:background="@color/shadow"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        style="@style/FABButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_import_export_white_24dp"
        app:backgroundTint="?attr/colorPrimary"
        />
    <include layout="@layout/fab_layout" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Just I attach my test. If you scroll through the hands, it works :)
But it is necessary robotized process.

```
    @Test
    public void addNewPhone(){
        onView(withId(R.id.widget_recycler_view)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(3));
        onView(withId(R.id.coordinator_layout)).perform(swipeUp());
        putDelay(2500);
        onView(withId(R.id.layout_add_phone)).perform(click());
        onView(withId(R.id.edit_letay_phone)).perform(replaceText("9586222922"));
        closeSoftKeyboard();
        onView(withText(R.string.add)).perform(click());
        closeSoftKeyboard();
        onView(withId(R.id.edit_code_letay_phone)).perform(replaceText("52461"));
        onView(withId(R.id.bt_code_request)).perform(click());
    }
```

My question is: **How do I hide the toolbar completely when scrolling the list or of the layout?**

Answer (score 11):

I use the following custom view action in my tests:

```
 public static ViewAction collapseAppBarLayout() {
    return new ViewAction() {
        @Override
        public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
            return isAssignableFrom(AppBarLayout.class);
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Collapse App Bar Layout";
        }

        @Override
        public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
            AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) view;
            appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
            uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
        }
    };
}
```

And the usage:

```
onView(withId(R.id.app_bar_layout)).perform(CustomViewActions.collapseAppBarLayout());
```

Keep it mind, you need to have animations disabled in the device settings, otherwise, Espresso will not wait for it to fully collapse before proceeding to the next step.

Comment: Add offset change listener to the appbarLayout and wait until idle there.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski Yup, this is an option. This will require registering and unregistering of the idling resource every time the action is used, which might be annoying, but will definitely remove the dependency on device animation setting. Unless there is a better way around it

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solution helped me with a problem I had when scrolling a recycler view: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49072631/2793394

Answer (score 0):

Sometime small smart things can solve your problem. Suppose if your menu is open and you presses a back button what it does? Yes it closes your open menu Right!!

You need to do exactly same thing. Just ask espresso to press back button

Espresso.pressBack()

That's it. You are done.