# Testing a RecyclerView: RecyclerViewActions isn't scrolling far enough

Tags: android, testing, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I want my espresso test to scroll a RecyclerView down until it's sees a certain view and clicks it.

Therefore I am using `RecyclerViewActions`:

```
onView(withId(R.id.recycler)).perform(
          RecyclerViewActions.scrollTo<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
                  hasDescendant(withText(R.string.title_item_x))
          )
)
Thread.sleep(2000)
onView(withId(R.id.recycler)).perform(
          RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItem<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
                  hasDescendant(withText(R.string.title_item_x)),
                  click()
          )
)
```

The test scrolls the RecyclerView down, but only about 50% of the needed amount. The click call crashes because of it.

Does somebody encountered something similar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason why the view action wasn't successul:

The app has a collapsible toolbar which was expanded before I started the scroll action. When I performed the scroll action the toolbar collapsed first and then the recycler view scrolled. Therefore the recycler view scrolled to little.

The solution I found is that I collapse the toolbar first with a custom AppBarViewAction. The solution is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40443373/2793394)